# Why Jackson needs a default constructor?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, controller, jackson

I am using Java Spring Boot for my project and I have the following controller:

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/subject")
public class SubjectController {
    private SubjectService subjectService;

    @PostMapping
    public void createSubject(@RequestBody SubjectCreationDTO subjectCreationDTO) {
        LoggingController.getLogger().info(subjectCreationDTO.getTitle());
//        subjectService.createSubject(subjectCreationDTO);
    }
}
```

And SubjectCreationDTO:

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
public class SubjectCreationDTO {
    private String title;
}
```

So I get this error when making a POST request:

> JSON parse error: Cannot construct instance of
> `pweb.examhelper.dto.subject.SubjectCreationDTO` (although at least
> one Creator exists): cannot deserialize from Object value (no
> delegate- or property-based Creator)"

I can solve this error by adding @NoArgsConstructor to `SubjectCreationDTO`, but why is this necessary, when in other cases, I have the almost exactly the same case.

```
@PostMapping
public ResponseEntity<StudentDTO> createStudent(@RequestBody StudentCreationDTO studentCreationDTO) {
    StudentDTO savedStudent = studentService.createStudent(studentCreationDTO);
    return new ResponseEntity<>(savedStudent, HttpStatus.CREATED);
}
```

and this is the `StudentCreationDTO` class:

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
public class StudentCreationDTO {
    private String username;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String email;
}
```

I have figured it out that in case of having more than just one field, you do not have to specify @NoArgsConstructor and Jackson Library can parse the input JSON from the body just as fine. My question is why it has this behavior, and why it can't parse if I have only one field in the class without the default constructor, but it can if I have multiple fields?

Comment: updated the visibility to public for the project at [oneCompiler](https://onecompiler.com/java/428tg3swr)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for Jackson to deserialize a Json, it either needs a default constructor or a method annotated with `@JsonCreator`. Without any of these two methods, Jackson is not able to instantiate an instance and raises an `InvalidDefinitionException`. This is what the error ***cannot deserialize from Object value (no delegate- or property-based Creator)*** is trying to say.

With a default constructor, Jackson first creates a default instance of the class and then injects the object's properties with each field read from the Json.

Likewise, with the `@JsonCreator` approach, Jackson first instantiates an object with only the properties specified as the parameters of the method annotated with `@JsonCreator`. Then, sets each remaining field from the Json into the object. The annotated method can be either a parameterized constructor or a static method.

Normally, you shouldn't be able to deserialize an object with just an `@AllArgsContructor`, but there must be some other configuration that handles a parameterized instantiation for you. Here is also an article from [Baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-exception#101-the-problem-no-default-constructor) where at point 10.1 shows a typical case of a class not being deserialized because it lacks of both a default constructor or a method annotated with `@JsonCreator`.

I've also attached an example that you can try at [oneCompiler](https://onecompiler.com/java/428tg3swr) where it shows how Jackson behaves when there is only a parameterized constructor and no default constructor or `@JsonCreator` method. Precisely, the example handles the following scenarios:

- StudentCreationDTO1 is not deserialized as it provides only an @AllArgsConstructor and no default constructor. In fact, an `InvalidDefinitionException` is thrown.
- StudentCreationDTO2 is deserialized as it provides a default constructor.
- StudentCreationDTO3 is deserialized as it provides a (constructor) method annotated with `@JsonCreator`. The annotation doesn't need to include all the class' fields, but only a few of them, just so that Jackson is able to create an instance of `StudentCreationDTO3` and then set the remaining fields.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException {
        String json = "{\n" +
                "\t\"username\": \"johndoe\",\n" +
                "\t\"firstName\": \"john\",\n" +
                "\t\"lastName\": \"doe\",\n" +
                "\t\"email\": \"john.doe@mail.com\"\n" +
                "}";
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

        //Deserializing with no default constructor
        try {
            StudentCreationDTO1 studentCreationDTO1 = objectMapper.readValue(json, StudentCreationDTO1.class);
            System.out.println(studentCreationDTO1);
        } catch (InvalidDefinitionException e) {
            System.out.println("Throwing InvalidDefinitionException because there is no default constructor or method marked with @JsonCreator");
        }

        //Deserializing with default constructor
        try {
            StudentCreationDTO2 studentCreationDTO2 = objectMapper.readValue(json, StudentCreationDTO2.class);
            System.out.println("\n" + studentCreationDTO2);
        } catch (InvalidDefinitionException e) {
            System.out.println("Throwing InvalidDefinitionException because there is no default constructor or method marked with @JsonCreator");
        }

        //Deserializing with no default constructor but with method annotated with @JsonCreator
        try {
            StudentCreationDTO3 studentCreationDTO3 = objectMapper.readValue(json, StudentCreationDTO3.class);
            System.out.println("\n" + studentCreationDTO3);
        } catch (InvalidDefinitionException e) {
            System.out.println("Throwing InvalidDefinitionException because there is no default constructor or method marked with @JsonCreator");
        }
    }
}
```

### Further Notes on Jackson Deserializtion

This is just an extra section that furthers how the deserialization process works, and shows why Jackson needs a first instance in order to read and set values from a Json. I'm also linking a great article from [Baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-field-serializable-deserializable-or-not) that addresses all the following cases for both serialization and deserialization.

- If a property has a setter, then its value is set via the corresponding setter method.

```
public class MyBean {
    private String name;

    //... default constructor ....

    //... standard getName() ...

    //Jackson uses the corresponding setter to set the property name
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

- If no setter is provided but the class exhibits a method annotated with `@JsonSetter` and the name of the Json property, then Jackson assumes that the annotated method is the right way to set the json property.

```
public class MyBean {
    private String name;

    //... default constructor ....

    //... standard getName() ...

    //Marking the following method with @JsonSetter because
    //The json contains a property called name (value = "name"), 
    //but Jackson can't find any setter method in the form setName()
    @JsonSetter(value = "name")
    public void setTheName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

- If no setter or `@JsonSetter` method is provided, but the class exhibits only getter methods, then Jackson falls back on reflection to set the object's properties.

```
public class MyBean {
    private String name;

    //... default constructor ....

    //Jackson cannot set a value with just a getter,
    //so it falls falls back to reflection to set name
    public void getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

- If a class doesn't provide any getter or setter, by default, Jackson sets only public fields, otherwise from any level of visibility and above when the `ObjectMapper` is configured with the `setVisibility()` method.

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.FIELD, Visibility.ANY);

...

public class MyBean {
    //Every field is set by Jackson with Visibility.ANY
    public String name;
    proteced int id;
    float value;
    private boolean flag;

    //... default constructor ....

    //... No getters or setters ....
}
```